# Should I use transitions with laminate flooring to control the size of plank needed at each wall?

Tags: laminate-floor, basement-refinishing, laminate

Im aware my questions sounds silly but the real issue is the basement im installing in has two bedrooms and a long family room. My understanding is that planks should be atleast 2 inches wide at the walls to maintain stength.

My worry is that i can measure the larger room and easilly cut the starting row so that the last row in that room is larger than 2 inches but if i continure into the bedrooms how do i adjust so that when i hit the wall in the bedrooms the last plank will be larger than 2 inches?

My initial thought is that i should use transitions in the doorways  to possibly adjust the size of my finishing row in each room, and i figure the room is large enough that i should have an expansion gap in the doorways anyway. I feel like this isnt the first complicated basment to ever have laminate used in it? Am i missing something obvious???

If you need any clarification let me know, i know it sounds kind of confusing. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

No. Narrow, sometimes tapered finishers are a fact of life. In practice most installers don't rip the starter row because it's inevitable. If the first room doesn't have an awkward finisher, the next one will. Or the kitchen island will.

Your 2" standard sounds like an ideal. Carpentry is more art than ideal. One tactic is to glue the finisher to the last full row to give it more support.

If you have trouble finishing a room due to a narrow strip, raise a new question and we'll help. Bring photos!